# JDBC Connection Pool Memory Issues (Java EE Application)

Tags: java, memory, jdbc, jvm

I currently have a Java EE application in which I have implemented my own connection pool class.  Each method I use does a simple query (Statement and ResultSet).  In the finally block of each method I use JDBC/my pool in, I first close the ResultSet, and then I close the Statement as many, many resources in books and online indicate should be done. Finally, I return the connection back to the pool.

While watching the memory of the JVM, I notice that the memory never really releases after I make a call which uses JDBC through my connection pool, or it takes a very long time to do so. I have checked my Garbage Collection settings and I am using gencon (IBM WebSphere), which many resources online have indicated is very good as well.  I am using Spring Framework in my application too.

The connection pool class I wrote is very simple. Upon initialization, it creates a certain number of connections to the database and adds them to a Queue (I tried another implementation with just a simple Vector, but same results with the memory). When you request a connection, it checks to make sure there's an available connection, and if so it gives one to the caller.  At the end, you return it back and it puts it back into the Queue/Vector.

I am wondering if there's anything else that could be done about this? Should I let Spring Framework handle my connection pool instead, or is there something else that handles the memory better?  To me, it does make sense, but I'm not too familiar with implementing connection pooling. All the resources say to do what I am doing, but I'm assuming they might be using some built in pooling implementation.  I do know that closing the connection works, but since this is a custom pooled solution, I cannot really do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely use an existing pool implementation, and definitely let Spring handle it for you. You're reiniventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your application running inside the WebSphere application server? Is it getting its datasource from the app server, rather than creating it itself? If so, then the connections and statements are already being pooled, and you don't need to pool them yourself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning WebSphere's built-in connection pooling. Completely forgot about it in my answer...

Comment: The application is running inside of WAS, yes.  I'm not sure if the data source is coming from the app server itself, but I don't think so.  The connections are being created as such:
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, pass);

Comment: That's a terrible way for using JDBC under a container. Is there a JDBC driver definition in your WebSphere configuration? and a Data Source definition?

Comment: I agree.  There is a JDBC driver definition, but not the data source definition. I'm going to add the data source definition and implement it that way. Seems much, much better.

Comment: I implemented it using WAS' built-in connection pooling. That is the last time I follow someone's lead of using a custom pooling solution. The built-in pooling seems to work better of course.

Answer (score 2):

OK, first thing's first: unless you have a very good reason, implementing your own connection pooling mechanism is an exercise in unnecessary risk. There's simply many connection pooling mechanisms out there to pick from - Spring would be one of them, Jakarta's DBCP being another. If you have the option of using a third-party utility for connection pooling - do it. If you're running inside a container, let the container do the work for you (WebSphere already does this, through its various "helper classes").

Regarding the symptoms you're experiencing: the fact that the memory isn't released, doesn't mean that there's a memory leak. It is up to the JVM to decide whether and when to actually free-up unreferenced object instances. Are you encountering OutOfMemory errors as well?

Start by issuing some heap dumps (right after JDBC resources' release) to see what's going on in there.

About the code you wrote - without posting the code, it's very hard to guesstimate whether you have hidden bugs there; but the flow you're describing appears correct.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I came into this code base as not the original author. A custom JDBC pooling mechanism was used elsewhere (no idea why the original author did this.  There's a comment in the code about "unfortunately we can't use Spring for this" but I'm not sure why that is). I followed his convention and did it as well).

Well, I know it's not a memory leak (technically there's no such thing as a memory leak in Java right? ;-)), but it is a "memory hog."  Our settings are very high, but we have run into out of memory issues before after a long time.

Comment: An old Turkish proverb says: "No matter how far you went the wrong way - go back."

Comment: I'm glad that's a Turkish proverb. I'm going to implement it in Spring and hopefully it will work. There's a comment in the code saying Spring didn't work or something to that effect, but who knows if they implemented it correctly.

Comment: I can see that you're using WebSphere. If you're running under a container, definitely don't use any connection pooling at all (not even Spring); WebSphere maintain its own connection pooling mechanism. All you have to do is obtain a connection from the `DataSource`, use it and release it at the end.